# Rails 3.2.0: Creating users in a controller other than Users controller (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Working on my first rails project so please pardon any incorrect terminology. I created a User model and Users controller. I also have a pages controller where I created my landing/home page. I want to have a form so that people can create an account (new user) on the home page.

To do this, I created a partial with the form in app/views/users and rendered it from the home page. When I try to load the page, I keep getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in Pages#home 
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Here are the relevant files:

app/views/users/_usersignup.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

   def home
    @title = "Home"
   end

   def new
    @user = User.new
   end
  end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
        @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Account created!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
        @title = "Sign up"
        render 'new'
    end
end
end
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The form needs @user to be an instance of User.  In your PagesController#home action , you need to instantiate it.

```
PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @title = 'Home'
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

Should do it for you.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! In this case, does users_controller.rb still require the code below since I'm creating the user through the pages controller?  

    `def new
      @user = User.new
      @title = "Sign up"
    end`

Comment: No, not if your never calling User#new.